# How to fast forward rewind my media player in C# silverlight windows mobile 7 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

**What I am making**
I am making a C# Silverlight Windows Mobile 7.5 Media player and I am using Medialibrary class. It is a simple media player and all it does is plays audio files(not video yet) stored on the phone in the zune library.

**The Problem**
Other things are going well but now I am stuck. There seems to be no way to provide a user with a Fast Forward / Rewind button.  I can go to next track but the only way to fast forward, rewind or scrub through the song is to press the volume keys and a menu comes up which is windows phone's own built in menu.

**What I tried so far**
I looked at audiobackgroundservice but that seems to be only for streaming media and can only access isolated storage and cant even access zune songs library.

**Blaming Gates as always**
This is such a simple thing, i cannot believe microsoft didnt provide the functionality to scrub through a song or fast forwarding/rewinding with code???????

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the position property of the player in your audio task. You need to call FastForward and Rewind within these functions. And you also need to handle the Seek action and within there set the player's Position property to the value of param (passed as an argument only when a seek is specified). This will give you the functionality you want.

You have to react to the `FastForward` or `Rewind` Action in the `OnUserAction` Callback.

**From Documentation**:

User actions do not automatically make any changes in system state; the agent is responsible for carrying out the user actions if they are supported.

Comment: OK for this to work I'd have to use a mediaelement control which I wasnt. Now I am happy using mediaelement control but I just did some reading up on it and I cant see how I can access the music library on the phone and get a list of all songs which I can then display in a list control for my happy user to play. It seems to only allow access to isolated storage, or am I missing something ? :(